# ViewPager does not show content

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I am trying to create a `ViewPager` that shows a list of ImageViews. I am able to implement the pager and adapter properly, and it works as expected on swiping. However, it does not show the content of the `ImageView` properly, i.e. the image itself. Its as if the images are there, but they are transparent. Only one image is visible out of the whole lot.

Here is my code-

**ImagePagerAdapter.java**

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ImageView> views = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean[] done = {false,false,false,false,false};
    ItemDetailFragment idf;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(ItemDetailFragment idf,
            LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.idf = idf;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(idf.getActivity());
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_grey_background);
            views.add(iv);
        }
    }

    public ImagePagerAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(inflater.getContext());
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_grey_background);
            views.add(iv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        if (done[position]) {
            return views.get(position);
        }
        ImageView v = views.get(position);
        views.set(position, v);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(v);
        done[position] = true;
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**ItemDetailFragment.java** : This is where I set the adapter.

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {
ViewPager pager;
ImagePagerAdapter adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
        container, false);
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new ImagePagerAdaper(this, inflater);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**fragment_item_detail.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.trial.piclist.ItemDetailFragment" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <include
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/controls_layout" />
    </TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/descScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hello" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

LayoutInflater Inflater;
Activity act;
int count;
public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity a, int c) {
    act = a;
            count=c;
    Inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            View v1 = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_image, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) v1
                .findViewById(R.id.about_image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_grey_background);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v1, 0);

    return v1;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Make a layout element_image.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/smv"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Replace

```
adapter = new ImagePagerAdaper(this, inflater);
```

with

```
adapter = new ImagePagerAdaper(getActivity(), count_of_images);
```

Comment: I tried it. There is a peculiar result. When I am swiping from image x+1 to image x, the image is visible. But as soon as the transition finishes, the image disappears. It stays only when x=0. So I can only see the first image permanently.

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet What count are you sending?

Comment: The count is constant. 5. Once it works out with a fixed count, I am planning to dynamically edit the count.

Comment: Can u post the screenshot of what you are getting and logcat?

Comment: My bad. I forgot to change the isViewFromObject and saveState methods (they were hidden by the scroll). Turns out the issue was in isViewFromObject method, it was always returning true earlier. Can you explain why and when this method is called?

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet To be honest, I am not sure. I used a sample to make this adapter. Maybe some little research will help you. Good luck! :)

Comment: :D Funny thing is that I saw that method implementation in the samples too when I was trying to make this adapter (I have used pager for the first time). But instead of obediently copying the code, I decided to use my head and mess it up.

Comment: @CodePro_NotYet That is a nice practice other than blindly using the code :)

Answer (score -1):

initiate the ImageView in the instantiateItem() method, set the LayoutParams of the imageView

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Also set the bg colour for debugging

```
 imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
 viewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: `LayoutParams` of `MATCH_PARENT` would not be suitable as it would cover the entire page. I have tried `WRAP_CONTENT` instead. The problem persisted. I have also used background color. For the image that is visible, the background color of the `ImageView` can be seen. But for the invisible images, the background of the `ViewPager` is seen.

Comment: I said incorrectly in the previous comment about `MATCH_PARENT`. I was thinking that I had set the length of the `ViewPager` to `WRAP_CONTENT`. However, I have now tried with `MATCH_PARENT` too but still getting the same result.